# Nested Knapsacks - Multiple knapsacks in one Knapsack

Tags: c#, algorithm, knapsack-problem

1. Is it even possible to implement?
2. Is the situation known as something different?
3. I need to write code in c#

The problem is somewhat very difficult; I did write the code to fill a knapsack and currently trying to write code to fill multiple knapsacks.

But currently I'm in a situation as below:

- There are 10 Large Boxes
- Each Large Box has different allowed Weight (Outer Knapsack)
- Every Large Box has different number of containers (Inner Knapsack)
- There is a Bag of Balls
- Each ball is eligible to be placed in few different containers
- Weight of Ball differs with the Inner Knapsack

Now I need to divide the balls into different containers in such a way that I have maximum allowed Value/Weight in the End (Sum of all Large Boxes).

Relaxation: Value and Weight are Same.

Is it even possible? I'll give the bounty to the correct answer!

Comment: What do you mean by "possible to implement"? Are you looking for an exact optimization algorithm or a heuristic approach?

Comment: Actually both! If I can get an algo awesome, but there's no exact algo but a way to implement. Than thats a i have to work with

Comment: Did you literally just ask for $1 Million? http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/p-vs-np-problem

Comment: @Aron I dont think so, I have set of eligible items for every position. But I really didnt know about it :D

Comment: You are asking for a solution to NP-Complete. Anyone with a practical solution to NP-Complete problems can win $1 Million from the Clay Institute. The problem isn't "very difficult". It is a famously unsolved problem in Mathematics, right up there with the Riemann Hypothesis.

Comment: @Aron To make some things clear: The problem stated above is a discrete optimization problem with some complicating constraints. There are two main approaches to such problems: The first would be writing the problem in variables and equations and solving it with a solver like CPLEX or Gurobi to optimality (these solvers can solve NP-complete problems; the speed depends on the problem size and the constraints). The other approach would be to implement some meta-heuristic like Tabu Search to find a good (but not necessarily optimal) solution.

Comment: NP-completeness is a theoretical concept. Many NP-hard problems can be solved in little time in practice. This is mainly true because the concept "NP-hard" only considers the worst case, but in many problems this worst case does not occur in practical problem instances.

Comment: @JFMeier The point is to recognize that this is an NP-Complete problem. The closest analog I've seen to this problem is the UPS ORION, which took 10 years to create...

Comment: @JFMeier NP-Complete != NP-Hard. If you can solve NP-Complete, I am sure UPS would be very happy to meet you, because their Cost is directly related to the optimization of the Traveling Salesman problem.

Comment: The Traveling Salesman Problem can be solved to optimality for networks of thousands of nodes.

Comment: Hey mate, did you end up finding an answer to this? @TaranGoel